# How many 3D printers have been in space?

Tags: reduced-gravity-manufacturing

The Phys.org article [Artificial meat is now made in space, coming to a supermarket near you](https://phys.org/news/2019-10-artificial-meat-space-supermarket.html) has me wondering

- how many 3D printers have been in space?
- how many 3D printers have been in space but not on the ISS i.e. have there been any on Chinese stations?

A bit of info on each would receive "extra credit", for example has it been tested yet, did it work?

Comment: companion question: [What replacement parts have been 3D printed on the ISS and then installed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39329/12102)

Comment: I can expand in an answer, but made in space first demoed and flew 3D printers in the late 2010s, University students have flown a couple, and tethers unlimited flew one to the ISS along with made in space. I think NASA has a web page on additive manufacturing where you might be able to find the results of the phase-3 contracts they've awarded.

Comment: @mothman "How many X..." questions are sometimes difficult to answer without it becoming a list question. But I expect that you have enough information to at least estimate the total, and I think that would be a helpful answer.